# Sending a file or byte array to input / file dialog in cefsharp

Tags: c#, file-upload, cefsharp

Hi I have a website with this input dialog:

```
<input name="file" id="image1.image" type="file" class="file">
```

The webbrowser control is cefsharp and I want to upload a file without using the dialog.

The file to upload is present as local or as byteArray in the mainprogram.

The simple worklow should be in my c# app I click "Upload" an the local file or the ByteArray will send to the input of the website.

Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) is useful for this?

Comment: It seems not to work with the File Api.

Comment: Hi. You can resolved?